# Is a class with static methods a legit way to avoid globals in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm learning Python by my self for a few weeks now and after searching and reading the whole internet I'm still not sure how to avoid global vars, dicts and lists the right way in Python. There are still lots of noisy 'meanings' about that topic (and as a beginner and non native english speaker, this is confusing).

Currently my attempt is to create a utility class with a kind of 'static' members and accessing them via static methods like as the following class:

```
class StaticLookupTables(object):

    # Example luts.
    # They can be quite large (but not huge)!
    _a = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    _b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

    _colors = {
        "green":       (0.25, 1.00, 0.25, 1.00),
        "yellow":      (1.00, 1.00, 0.00, 1.00),
        "white":       (1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
    }

    @staticmethod
    def is_in_a(ident):
        return True if ident in _a else False

    @staticmethod
    def is_in_b(ident):
        return True if ident in _b else False

    @staticmethod
    def is_in_c(ident):
        return True if ident in _c else False

    @staticmethod
    def get_socket_color(ident):
        try:
            return _colors[ident]

        except KeyError:
            return (0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00)
```

Where needed I use this class as follow:

```
from .util import StaticLookupTables as SLT
#
# ... more code ...
#
if SLT.is_in_a(var):
    do_things_when_var_is_in_a()
```

Thank you and a happy new year.

Comment: You do not need globals, you can provide functions wich parameters or use classes with internal variables.

Comment: Personally I don't think you should be avoiding everything to be out from global scope, and move them to class. Sometimes it is ok to leave it in global scope.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really designed for opinions.  If you have working code and want opinions on it, one place to go is https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your ternary's are not needed, `return ident in _c` is sufficient.

Comment: If you move globals into a class, and make them static members, you're basically just using the class to create a namespace. I would say that namespaced globals are far better than non-namespaced globals. Namespacing solves the name collision problem with globals at least.

Comment: Have you run this code? It cannot be staticmethods because you're referencing class attributes within them, therefor you'll need a classmethod.

Comment: For this simple usecase you don't need the upper methods, you can just check `'A' in SLT._a` and it will return True or False

Comment: @Darkonaut you are right, thank you. I think I've understand it now.